# Trying to request fundamental data from TWS API

Tags: python, api, import, python-requests

I'm pretty new to this api and python in general, I'm trying to import fundamental data from the TWS api by interactive brokers.

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract

wrapper = EWrapper()
app = EClient(wrapper)
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, clientId=123)

print("serverVersion:%s connectionTime:%s" % (app.serverVersion(), app.twsConnectionTime()))

contract = Contract()
contract.symbol = 'SQ'
contract.secType = 'STK'
contract.currency = 'USD'

app.reqFundamentalData(8001, contract, 'RESC', [])
```

This is the documentation: https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/fundamentals.html

I can't manage to find if the data for this request was imported and where it was imported to.

Would be really thankful to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 4):

There are **two main classes** in Interactive Brokers API that handle msg between client and server, they are:

**1. EClient: in charge of sending requests to IB's server;**

**2. EWrapper: in charge of receiving msg sent back from IB's server.**

**reqFundamentalData() function is in EClient class**, it is in charge of sending fundamental data requests to IB's server.

After IB server received request, it will send back the text data to EWrapper class for it to handle. Another function **fundamentalData() in EWrapper class** is called to handle the returned data.

And before sending out any requests to IB's server, EWrapper and EClient classes have to be initialized, and the relevant receiving functions have to be overwritten to implement other personalized functions. Such as print the data received, or saving the returned data to any database, etc.

```
# Import EWrapper and EClient   
from ibapi.Contract import Contract    
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper    
from ibapi.client import EClient    
    
    # Initilizing
    class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
        def __init__(self):
            EClient.__init__(self, self)
        
        # Error handling function
        def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
            print("error: ", reqId, " ", errorCode, " ", errorString)
    
        # Inherite and overwrite fundamentalData() function in EWrapper
        def fundamentalData(self, reqId: int, data: str):
            super().fundamentalData(reqId, data)
            print("FundamentalData Returned. ReqId: {}, Symbol: {},  XML Data: {}".format(
                reqId, contr.symbol, data))
            # Implement other personalized functions here
    
    tws = IBapi()                       
    tws.connect("127.0.0.1",port=7496, clientId=997)
    time.sleep(2)
    
    c = Contract()
    c.m_symbol = 'MMM'
    c.m_secType = 'STK'
    c.m_exchange = "SMART"
    c.m_currency = "USD"
    
    tws.reqFundamentalData(1, c, 'RESC', [])
    time.sleep(4)
    # Implement other requests
    
    tws.disconnect()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for good explanation and understandable code. I had to replace "from ibapi.Contract" with "from ibapi.contract import Contract" and fix class indent

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for "ReportsFinStatements":

```
from ib.opt import ibConnection, message
from ib.ext.Contract import Contract
from time import sleep

def fundamentalData_handler(msg):
    print(msg)

def error_handler(msg):
    print(msg)

tws = ibConnection("127.0.0.1",port=7496, clientId=997)
tws.register(error_handler, message.Error)
tws.register(fundamentalData_handler, message.fundamentalData)
tws.connect()

c = Contract()
c.m_symbol = 'MMM'
c.m_secType = 'STK'
c.m_exchange = "SMART"
c.m_currency = "USD"

tws.reqFundamentalData(1,c,'ReportsFinStatements')

sleep(2)

tws.disconnect()
```

Comment: Code does not work.  Error:   from ib.opt import ibConnection, message
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ib'